# RCDevice is taking too long time to initialise

Tags: android, restcomm

I used [restcomm](https://www.restcomm.com/) to make audio call in my app.
Because of initialisation issue sometimes getting error message that 'peer not found' so it fails to connect audio call.
I also know that it depends on network connection.
But i need some suggestion that How can i overcome this issue?